# How to get downloaded UIImage data from TTPhoto

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I use TTPhotoViewController and TTPhoto to display images.
I want to get UIImage data from displayed TTPhoto and I checked these protocols but I couldn't find any methods or properties for it.

Is there any way to get displayed UIImage data in TTPhotoViewController?

Thank you.

Comment: Emmettoc, Mind sharing your answer with the rest of us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can download the data your self and then send to the three20 your local path to load the photos.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Yes, I can, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. So I'm glad if there is a simply way.

Comment: I answered my own question. Thank you.